# Getting year to update and archive dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a menu that inserts the current year and archives the previous years dynamically.  I have the below nested within a `<ul id="Year_Menu">`

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$nxt_yr = date("Y", strtotime('+1 years'));


if ($current_year >= $nxt_yr) {

    $recent_past_year = $current_year -1;
    $years = array($current_year, $recent_past_year, "2018", "2017", "2016");

} else {

    $years = array($current_year, "2018", "2017", "2016");
}

        foreach ($years as $value) {

        echo "<li><a href='blog_posts.php?month=01&yr=$value;'>$value</a></li>";

        }
</ul>
```

This works for this year and the next, but in 2021 the jig is up :) I can keep creating `elseif` statements & go up to 2030 (or whatever) but talk abt inefficient.  I'm not already thinking this is the most efficient btw, but still learning, I'm trying to figure out a better way to do this, so that `$recent_past_year` ends up archiving, and the rest of the code just keeps moving forward.

How can I get `$recent_past_year` in 2021 (& beyond) to dynamically archive within the `$years` array?  ...stuck

Comment: Can you rephrase exactly what you're trying to display? That seems unclear to me. You want the list of years going from which to which year?

Comment: The display will be a bullet list with 2019 at the top `$current_year`, then 2018, 2017, 2016 where it stops.  When it roles over to 2020, the` if` statement will evaluate to true the `$current_year` will now be 2020, `$recent_past_year` will be 2019, then 2018, 2017 etc.  When the year roles over to 2021, there is no script avail. to support the array correctly.  I will have 2016, 2017, 2018, 2020, 2021.  IOW 2019 will be missing.  I want that archive dynamically in the array...somehow.  I'm trying to figure it out right now with a `while` loop & operators.  no luck yet...

Comment: Still unclear to me. I'm not trying to undersand your code, but what you want to achieve. Do you want a list of years going from the current year to 2016 specifically? Or 3 years before the current year? What's specific about 2021? Try to explain your goal regardless of your current code.

Comment: I want to display years starting at 2016 and continuing on to infinity.  What's specific abt 2021 in relation to my code is this is where the script will begin to display incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to get the years using the current year as the start:

```
$current_year = date("Y");
$years = range(intval($current_year), 2016);
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($years as $value) {
    echo "<li><a href='blog_posts.php?month=01&yr=$value;'>$value</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Result**

- 2019
- 2018
- 2017
- 2016

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/VcL9h)

Comment: ty - works perfectly.  presently reading up on `range()` which is new to me.  I knew there had to be something better than the avenue I was taking.  I was in the process of using a `while loop` with operators to evaluate the previous years.  ugh.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP function `range`.

Example:

```
<?php

$thisYear = 2019;
$yearsFrom2016 = array_reverse(range(2016, $thisYear));
```